# Facebook connect in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook

How can I integrate Facebook Connect to my project, I want to show Facebook Connect in a button click. My requirement is to share a text to Facebook via Facebook Connect.

How to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tutorials might interest you..

http://amanpages.com/wordpress/sample-iphone-example-project/facebookagent-easy-way-to-integrate-facebook-connect-in-iphone-apps-and-write-minimum-code-to-publish-feed-change-status/

http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/